# How to count brands, featured in multiple categories

Tags: mysql

In earnest, I am not sure what to search for to autonomously answer my question and my SQL knowledge is abhorrent.

How can I modify my SQL query; to present distinct brands, that are present in 3 or more categories, and the categories they preside in?

For example, Nike should only show; as Samsung is present in only 2 categories.

```
SELECT      DISTINCT(brand),
            category
FROM        products
ORDER BY    category, 
            brand
```

```
Brand | category
-----------------
Nike    | Baby
Nike    | Footwear
Nike    | Pets
Samsung | TVs
Samsung | Baby
```

Having Google's I think there is a concept of subqueries and I might need a HAVING :s

Comment: Please show sample data and wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the brands if you `group by brand` and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select brand 
from products
group by brand
having count(distinct category) >= 3
```

If you also want the categories use the above query as a subquery with the operator IN:

```
select distinct brand, category
from products
where brand in (
    select brand 
    from products
    group by brand
    having count(distinct category) >= 3
)
```

Remove `distinct` if there is no case of dulicates.

Comment: thank you the second query answered everything and I've gained exposure to the syntax to help me in the future. Thank you.